# Detecting the device type when an angular universal app pre-rendered on the server

Tags: angular, angular-universal, device-detection

I'm using [ngx-device-detector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-device-detector) library for detecting the device type (mobile, tablet or desktop).
This library working perfectly in client mode but can't detect the device type when an angular universal application pre-rendered on the server(after prerendering on the server, working perfectly on client mode).

1. I appreciate if someone gives me a solution that works for this library
2. Eventually, if there isn't any solution for this library, give me another solution

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No there isn't any error. But can't detect the device type when an angular universal application pre-rendered on the server

Comment: Which version are you using? According to github issues, this should work from v 1.4.1 onwards

Comment: I use version 1.4.2. In version 1.4.1 the author just adds the "isPlatformBrowser" condition to handle the error only.  It hasn't been working for pre-rendering on the server yet to detect device type.

Comment: You are right, I did not check the code. Maybe using a library like that? https://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/

Comment: @David Can't we use this library by addressing the path of server.ts (e.g. const {ngx-device-detector} = require('./dist/server/main')) in our angular universal express.js server?

Comment: Did you already provide the request object to your angular components, from angular universal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a quick look at the code and I think you can call `setDeviceInfo` with a user agent string that you can retrieve from the request headers

**app.module.ts**

```
import {Request} from 'express';
import {REQUEST} from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId, 
            @Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) protected request: Request,
            private deviceService: DeviceDetectorService)
{
    if(!isPlatformBrowser(platformId))
    {
        this.deviceService.setDeviceInfo(request.headers['user-agent']);
    }
}
```